# Does micronaut/Netty create separate thread for Client call?

Tags: netty, micronaut

I am unable to understand the micronaut documentation when they as `if your interactions with an HTTP client involve CPU-intensive work, it may be worthwhile configuring a separate EventLoopGroup for one or all clients.`

Would separate thread would be used for calling the HTTP Client ?

Let's say there are two services `service-A` and`service-B` and a request come to `serviceA` to fetch some data , to fetch data service-A will call to service-B via some HTTP Client. So how the threads will be created/picked for the above scenario ?

When request comes to `service-A`, a new thread(let's say `nio-EventLoopGroup-1`) will be assigned to request from event-loop and when service-A tries to call service-B, then again another new thread (`nio-EventLoopGroup-2`) will be assigned to that  HttpClient task.

Two question on the above scenario :

1. If new thread (`nio-EventLoopGroup-2`) will assigned to HttpClient call then what will happend to the first thread (`nio-EventLoopGroup-1`) ?
2. If same thread (`nio-EventLoopGroup-1`) will be calling to the client then what is the meaning of creating separate event-loop for client call ?